# Should I create the "Id" property when modeling a LINQ cosmos db?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Let's suppose that I want to create the following document

```
{
    "Id": "6a23a5f3-0f77-40a9-b9f9-26e88537a962",
    "CarHistory": [
        { "model":"ford", "price": 100, "kilometers": 100  "current": true },
        { "model":"ford", "price": 200, "kilometers": 200, "current": false },
    ]
}
```

In Poco I guess that the model could look something among these lines:

```
public class Document
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Car : Document
{
    public string Model {get; set;}
    public decimal Price {get; set;}
    public int Kilometers {get; set;}
    public bool Current {get; set;}
}
```

So later I create..

```
public class MasterCar : Document
{
    public ICollection<Car> CarHistory { get; set; } = new List<Car>();
}
```

All seems to work fine while debugging:
I create the Guid programmatically somewhere in a service like:

```
var masterCar = new MasterCar(){ Id = Guid.NewGuid() }
```

but when I go to the cosmos db emulator and a `SELECT * FROM` , and I checkout the Id property its value is:

```
"id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
```

Can someone point me what Im doing wrong? or how this should be accomplished, I read that
you should not provide an Id yourself, BUT how can I access the Id property programmatically then?
For example:

```
CarService.GetById(Car.Id); //Id property doesnt exist if there is no property in poco
```

Comment: Cosmos (or potentially, the EF cosmos driver), creates it's own "id" field, that is nothing to do with the "Id" field that you generally find in EF classes.  Our database has both `Id` and `id` fields.

Comment: @Neil That's not true, you can provide your own  value for the `id`. @Rodrigo, please show a full example of the item that gets created by your code, as seen in the emulator?

Comment: It's true for my project @NoahStahl !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is my test code, you can have a try:

Document.cs

```
public class Document
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

Car.cs

```
public class Car
{
    [JsonProperty("model")]
    public string Model { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("price")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("kilometers")]
    public int Kilometers { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("current")]
    public bool Current { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
    }
}
```

MasterCar.cs

```
public class MasterCar : Document
{
    public ICollection<Car> CarHistory { get; set; } = new List<Car>();

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
    }
}
```

create and search:

```
        var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        var masterCar = new MasterCar() { Id = guid };
        var car = new Car() { Model = "ford", Price = 100, Kilometers = 100, Current = true };
        var car2 = new Car() { Model = "ford", Price = 200, Kilometers = 200, Current = false };
        var carHistory = masterCar.CarHistory;
        carHistory.Add(car);
        carHistory.Add(car2);

        CosmosClient client = new CosmosClient(connection_string);
        Container container = client.GetContainer(databaseId, containerName);
        await container.CreateItemAsync<MasterCar>(masterCar);

        ItemResponse<MasterCar> itemResponse =  await container.ReadItemAsync<MasterCar>(guid.ToString("D"), new PartitionKey(guid.ToString("D")));
        Console.WriteLine(itemResponse.Resource.ToString());
```

Result:

[image]

[image]